# No warning when using a Collection Initializer on an embedded collection in an Object Initializer

Tags: c#, .net

**Given**

```
public class SomeClassWithAList
{
    public List<int> list { get; set; }
}

[Fact]
public void InitListInsideModel()
{
    var cashthing = new SomeClassWithAList { list = { 4 } };
}
```

My issue is that it appears `InitListInsideModel` is a valid code, but this code actually won't execute.

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.

What's going on here? What basic concept am I not understanding? Is this a compiler bug? Why does IntelliSense not warn me I cannot instantiate a list this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR**

The fix, as you know would be to initialize the collection one way or another

```
public List<int> list { get; set; } = new List<T>();

// or

var cashthing = new SomeClassWithAList
{
    list = new List<int>(){ 4 }
};
```

---

As to why you can do this and not get a warning? Well... this is an interesting issue.

At first glance, it looks like a *roslyn* bug which is allowing invalid array initializer syntax on a collection within an object Initializer.

However, it is actually by design. What the syntax is doing, is adding a *sequence* using the *resolution* of the collections `Add` method. For this to work, the collection needs to be initialized!

<sub>*You learn something new every day*</sub>

**The following**

```
var cashthing = new SomeClassWithAList
{
    list = { 4 }
};
```

[**Compiles to**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALAPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSoDc6cAzLgtgMLYDe62DuZi2AygPYC2AppQDYBDAM5CA6gEsALgAsAggBlxQyejppGTbIuUAecQDtJAPmx8lk2tgDm3SQWxDb9gL7pXaeo1K4o2ALIAFACUtJ4a4QwAbgIATtgAxsLSMgZW2AC82PrcAO5sXLyCIhIyCuZhEWoREWbKGZa+7tUMzkTqjO7OQA===)

```
new SomeClassWithAList().list.Add(4);
```

IMO, *static analysis* should be able to warn for this (and especially with nullable types), it should also be well documented in [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

The only place I could find suitable documentation was in the *C# Language Specifications*

<sub>*Emphasis mine*</sub>

> **7.6.10.2 Object initializers**
>
> ...
>
> A member initializer that specifies a collection initializer after the
> equals sign is an initialization of an embedded collection. **Instead of
> assigning a new collection to the field or property, the elements
> given in the initializer are added to the collection referenced by the
> field or property. The field or property must be of a collection type
> that satisfies the requirements specified in §7.6.10.3**.

So the correct usage of this feature, is to make sure your collection is *auto initialized*

```
public List<int> list { get; set; } = new List<T>();
```

---

**Additional Resources**

After digging around some more, I found the following

- GitHub issue talking about this exact situation

  - [C# compiler allows bad object initializer syntax on nested objects](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/25508)
- GitHub issue wanting to add more specificity to the documentation to clarify the language feature

  - [Document nested object initializers](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/4686)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to instantiate `list` somewhere ...

Either in the assignment you currently have:

```
var cashthing = new SomeClassWithAList { new List<int> list = { 4 } };
```

Or in the `list` declaration:

```
public List<int> list { get; set; } = new List<int>();
```

Or in the `SomeClassWithAList` class constructor:

```
public SomeClassWithAList()
{
    list = new List<int>();
}
```

All of those options compile and run.